# cPanel - Does restoring from a cPanel backup delete other cPanel backups made at a future date than the one you’re restoring from?

Tags: backup, cpanel

I plan on restoring from a cPanel backup using the cPanel Backup Wizard, but I would like to know if restoring from a backup in this way will delete any other cPanel backups that were made at a future date from the one I’m restoring from?

Specifically, I have backups generated on 10/1 and 10/5 (earlier today). If I restore from the backup on 10/1, will it delete the backup I created on 10/5?

**Additional Details**

I'm on a Bluehost VPS server running CentOS 6.7.

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on the situation on which path you are trying to restore the backup. If you restore the 10/1 backup at the same path where your secnd copy 10/5 is present, then it will delete that same copy